# Gruntjs changing underscore template delimiters

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to generate a JSP page, and since the template delimiters used by JSP's are the same as the ones used by underscore.

looking at the docs --> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.template#wiki-grunt-template-setDelimiters i can see they have a function for that

```
grunt.template.addDelimiters(name, opener, closer)
```

Two questions:

1. Where would i call that function ?
2. Can i change the delimiters only for a `grunt.template.process()` ( i have more than one, and for other non .jsp templates, the default delimiters are fine ) ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried... escaping the characters, for when it processes the text, it gets printed the way you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from the documentation for **grunt.template.process**:

*The default template delimiters are <% %> but if options.delimiters is set to a custom delimiter name, those template delimiters will be used instead.*

that basically would mean that you can call grunt.template.process with the name of the delimiter you added before.

e.g. if you want to use square-brackets as delimiters in one processing step that should do the job:

```
// first add the new delimiters which you want to use
grunt.template.addDelimiters('square-brackets', '[', ']');

//  and use it
grunt.template.process(template, {delimiters: 'square-brackets'});

// and use it with the default delimiters (named 'config')
grunt.template.process(template);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue. JSP uses <%= %> tags for its replacement which are also used by grunt.
Added a line to overwrite the default setting applied in "https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/template.js"

This worked for me:

```
// REPLACE the default 'config' delimiters
grunt.template.addDelimiters('config', '{%', '%}');

grunt.initConfig(
    { .... });
```

The delimiter name 'config' must match exactly.